# Jolt Transform in NIFI for JSON with data massage

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I have the following JSON

```json
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "doe",
  "age": 26,
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "naist street",
    "city": "Nara",
    "postalCode": "630-0192"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type": "iPhone",
      "number": "0123-4567-8888"
    },
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "0123-4567-8910"
    }
  ]
}
```

Would like to transform this into:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "age": 26,
    "address": {
      "streetAddress": "naist street",
      "city": "Nara",
      "postalCode": "630-0192"
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
      {
        "type": "iPhone",
        "number": "0123-4567-8888"
      },
      {
        "type": "home",
        "number": "0123-4567-8910"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do this in Jolt?  I am just looking to wrap that JSON into a json data field.  NIFI storing to attributes was messing up with my data format.

Answer (score 0):

```
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "data.&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "data": {}
    }
  }
```

does the trick

Comment: though this resort my data

Comment: the first spec nested with square brackets will do what you want